# Multiple Typescript files compiled into self-contained javascript file

Tags: typescript, webpack, gulp, gruntjs

I know there are 1000s of these questions out there. I've looked through them all (mostly).

All the answers I've found seem to be outdated, changed, use a discontinued NPM packages, or a package with a 2 year old bug report on the error I'm getting.

I'm open to using any task runner, packages, import format, whatever.

I would like to write Typescript (something) like this:

File1:

```
import FileTwoClass from "./File2"
export default FileOneClass{
    fieldOne:number = 12

    doStuff(){
        FileTwoClass.importantFunction(this.fieldOne)
    }
}
```

File: App.ts:

```
import FileOneClass from "./File1" 
class App{
    run(){
        FileOneClass.doStuff();
    }
}

let app = new App()
app.run();
```

And have a taskrunner (or anything) spit out one single file that holds all dependencies set up in the linked Typescript files.

Am I going about this the wrong way, or is this attainable?
If so, precisely how? :D

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. If anyone comes by and finds this, use the guide here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/gulp.html

And use  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1", instead of the es2015 preset.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var tsify = require('tsify');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    return browserify({
        basedir: '.',
        debug: true,
        entries: ['ts/app.ts'],
        cache: {},
        packageCache: {}
    })
        .plugin(tsify)
        .transform('babelify', {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
            extensions: ['.ts']
        })
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```